# Slickgrid rowselection model

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Couple of question on the rowselection example in slickgrid http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html

1. Is it possible to link the row selection columns to a boolean data field i.e. the grid will render a tick if the data for that cell is TRUE or leave it un-ticked?
2. Is it possible to give the header a name (next to the header checkbox)?

Comment: Yes for both question. Slickgrid is very programmable so you can customized any way you like as long as you are willing to do the plumbing.

Comment: @RosdiKasim - Have you got an example which does both of the above please?